# What does "Lit is such a Light" mean in the translation of quran 24:36

Tags: quran, tafseer, quran-translation

There is a [question on travel.stackexchange.com](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135280/need-help-identifying-translating-a-plaque-in-tangier-morocco/135286?noredirect=1#comment336145_135286) which has a translation of the Quran verse [24:36](https://quran.com/24/36?translations=21,20,19,101,84,85,22,18,95,17) as

> فِي بُيُوتٍ أَذِنَ اللَّهُ أَن تُرْفَعَ وَيُذْكَرَ فِيهَا اسْمُهُ يُسَبِّحُ لَهُ فِيهَا بِالْغُدُوِّ وَالْآصَالِ

(Lit is such a Light) in houses, which Allah hath permitted to be raised to honour; for the celebration, in them, of His name: In them is He glorified in the mornings and in the evenings, (again and again)

And we need to know what "Lit is such a Light" does mean ?

Comment: There's a typo in the answer on travel.se the author used the letter ص instead of ط and wrote صرف instead of طرف.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lit is such a Light" is not part of the original Arabic, rather an insertion by the translator. In particular, it is alluding to the previous verse of the Qur'an:

> Allah is the Light of the heavens and the earth. The example of His light is like a niche within which is a lamp, the lamp is within glass, the glass as if it were a pearly [white] star lit from [the oil of] a blessed olive tree, neither of the east nor of the west, whose oil would almost glow even if untouched by fire. Light upon light. Allah guides to His light whom He wills. And Allah presents examples for the people, and Allah is Knowing of all things.
>
> <sup>[[An-Nur 35](http://legacy.quran.com/24/35)]</sup>

Basically, the Light here is a metaphor for Allah Himself, and tying the two verses together as the translator has done implies that Allah's Light is also present in these "houses", here referring to the houses of worship erected in His name (i.e. mosques).

Answer (score -3):

In houses. .. the women reciting quran with fear and love of ALLAH

Comment: Any evidence for this claim? (See [answer]).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but I asked about "Lit is such a Light" not "In houses", and even so, **Where is the evidence** ?, *BTW, I didn't downvote you*